# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have the below code for selenium

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("C:\\path\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.get("http://hedtq01vr.bcbsma.com:8080/tm/index.jsp?default");

    driver.quit();

}
```

When i try to run it fails with the below error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver`

Below are the jars on the build path:

- Selenium-java-2.42.2.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar

and IEDriverServer.exe on the **C:\path** folder

Why am i getting this error..The [page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) here doesn't talk anything about the required libraries.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

After adding the libraries from the selenium folder, I am getting the below error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE`

Here is the complete error [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=izudaPnb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Selenium download comes as a ZIP file ([selenium-java-2.42.2.zip](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-java-2.42.2.zip)), which contains not only Selenium-java-2.42.2.jar, but also a sub-directory named 'libs', and which contains a whole raft of JAR libraries that the Selenium jar presumably relies on. Among others the libs folder contains httpclient-4.3.2.jar, which is the Apache HTTP component containing the class your current setup cannot find.
Add all the jars in the libs directory on your build path (and then on your classpath at runtime), and you should be sorted.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply..When i add the libraries given in the `lib` folder i am getting the below error:

Comment: OK, getting into guesswork now, but I noticed you have "selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" on your path, which, if used (and I'm not sure of that), may cause version incompatibilities. Why not make use of the matching version 2.42.2?

Comment: Having had a closer look, the version incompatibility theory is looking more likely: the class that is failing in your exception stack is contained in the server jar file, and as it's not the same version as the java jar, they could clash. 
BTW, are you sure you need the server jar on your path? Typically you write code for the client or for the server, but not both at once. Sharing client and server libraries on the same project can lead to such issues.

Comment: And to add to the point, the [selenium setup instruction page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp) indicates that you should "Add the selenium-java-<version-number>.jar files to your project as references", and does not mention the server jar.